# PyQt4 - Cannot use QObject's functions in class inherited from QGraphicsItem (which inherits QObject)

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt, pyqt4

I wrote python code looking something like this:

```
class Regularblock(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QGraphicsItem).__init__()
        self.startTimer(100)
    def timerEvent(self, QTimerEvent):
        do_something
```

But when I try to initialize an instance of Regularblock, I get "AttributeError: 'Regularblock' object has no attribute 'startTimer'". Why does this happen? Am I missing something big?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: I think `QGraphicsItem` is not actually a subclass of `QObject`. Have a look [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html); it is not listed as one of the `QOject`'s direct subclasses. I'm not 100% sure, but perhaps you should be using `QGraphicsObject` ?

Comment: Huh. Whatever documentation I've ben using must be wrong. I also tried using class.__bases__ . From using it, I saw that QGraphicsItem actually inherits sip.wrapper. Whatever the case, thank you

Comment: Until looking this up, I also thought that `QObject` was pretty much universal as a base class -- who knew :) In related news, please check this answer if this was, in fact, your the solution to your issue.

Comment: Yep. I checked it (changing to QGraphicsObject) It works now :)